# Can i get chat id with pyrogram?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I want to know, is there a way, to get a of a chat which i'm joining my bot to?(using pyrogram)
like, i created a chat manager bot, and when i'm joining him to chat, i want him to work in this specific chat.
But every function like get_chat_members() needs target id.
how do it get this?

Comment: For extremely basic questions like these I'd recommend having a read through the [Documenatation](https://pyrogram.org), as well as ask their [support chat](https://t.me/pyrogramchat)

Comment: Try this document :- https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_dialogs. Don't confuse with 'dialogs' words.

Answer (score 0):

i already found a solution
You can get in through a message form that chat.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **get_chat()** module or **Client.get_chat()**

**EXAMPLE:**

```
x1 = user_name # use for private chat (str)
x2 = @user_name # use for chanlle (str)
x3 = https://t.me/+fc87J6mdsvdYmI0 # use for group (str)
x4 = chat_id # !!!!! (int)


chat = await app.get_chat(x1)
chat_id = chat.id
```

check [pyrogram doc](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_chat)